# How to read a parameter coming from controller in the view file in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, parameters, view, routes

I have an array that only have numbers called $questionsNumbers

This is my route in web.php file:

```
Route::get('student/evaluation/{evaluation}', [EvaluationController::class, 'getEvaluationQuestions'])->middleware('auth')->name('student.questionsevaluation');
```

And in the method in my controller I have this code to send the data to the view:

```
return redirect()->route('student.questionsevaluation', $evaluation)
->with('message', 'Question answered.')
->with('questionsNumbers', $questionsNumbers);
```

I've tried to show the numbers of the array $questionsNumbers in the view file in this way:

```
{{$questionsNumbers}}
```

But it not works, how can I show all the numbers that contains the array in the view?

Comment: That is how you do it... is `message` working?

Comment: message is working this way:                                                                                               @if (Session::has('message'))
            <div class="bg-gray-200 rounded-xl p-6 overflow-hidden text-2xl font-bold mb-2">
                {{Session::get('message')}}
            </div>@endif

Comment: But I need to show the elements of the array In the view file but I don't know how to do it

Comment: My bad, I forgot that using `with` is just for "flashing" the Session, not sharing stuff to the view, because you are redirecting to a route, so you cannot share data to a view. `redirect()->route('xxxx')`, is going to redirect to that route, you are not loading a new view, so you cannot share data to that route's view

Comment: Is there any mode to pass the array to the view? In other cases I tried with compact in the redirect->route() method but in this case I don't know how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a parameter coming from the with method to the view in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017279/how-to-read-a-parameter-coming-from-the-with-method-to-the-view-in-laravel)

Comment: @JeffersonFarid do not duplicate a question, just wait for it to get answers please

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to your `message`, you should do like this::

```
@if (Session::has('questionsNumbers'))
    @foreach (Session::get('questionsNumbers') as $number)
        <div>{{ $number }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```